# How to enable VP8 on iOS WebRTC?

Tags: ios, webrtc, vp8

How to enable VP8 on iOS WebRTC? I have build webrtc on ios and I can see libvpx in webrtc source code for ios. However I do not know how to enable it.

PeerConnection to createOffer only has h264 and there was no VP8 description in SDP.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `preferedCodec` for `RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory`:

```
let encoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory()

// Set video codec to VP8
encoderFactory.preferredCodec = RTCVideoCodecInfo(name: kRTCVideoCodecVp8Name)

let factory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory(
    encoderFactory: encoderFactory,
    decoderFactory: RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory()
)
```

Comment: It's worked for me guy, thanks.